# How to find user location based on EditText value

Tags: android, android-location

I am trying to get user's city from `EditText` and then check if it is valid or not. If there is a little typo, then I want to correct it on the `EditText` and then show it back to user.

I have been searching for this for quite some time but what I am getting is to get user current location and then get its location according to lat and long values. But I don't want to do this.

Here's what I am doing right now, but I don't want to do it this way

```
userDataFrag.loc.requestLocationUpdates(
    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider,
                int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            userLat = location.getLatitude();
            userLong = location.getLongitude();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(),
                Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses;
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(userLat,
                    userLong, 1);
                CityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                StateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
                CountryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Can any one suggests me a better way to do it?

Comment: what is the set of cities you have which user can input?

Comment: can be any city across the world